# Optional Parameters in Sanic Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, sanic

I want to take some optional body parameters in sanic server, just like we do in python.

Example in Python:

```
def func(a, b=1098):
    return a+b

print(func(2, 2))
print(func(1))
```

The same thing, I would like to do with sanic server request parameters. For now, I just simply use try block but would like to know a more efficient approach of it.

```
try:
    data = request.form['data'][0]
except Exception:
    data = 5
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would with any other dict object.

```
data = int(request.form.get("data", 5))
```

https://sanic.dev/en/guide/basics/request.html#body

*FYI - I wrapped it in`int` because form data usually will be a string otherwise.*